# Transform vs. aggregate in Pandas groupby

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, aggregation

When grouping a Pandas DataFrame, when should I use `transform` and when should I use `aggregate`?  How do
they differ with respect to their application in practice and which one do you
consider more important?

Answer (score 86):

consider the dataframe `df`

```
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(A=list('aabb'), B=[1, 2, 3, 4], C=[0, 9, 0, 9]))
```

[image]

---

`groupby` is the standard use aggregater

```
df.groupby('A').mean()
```

[image]

---

maybe you want these values broadcast across the whole group and return something with the same index as what you started with.
***use `transform`***

```
df.groupby('A').transform('mean')
```

[image]

```
df.set_index('A').groupby(level='A').transform('mean')
```

[image]

---

***`agg`*** is used when you have specific things you want to run for different columns or more than one thing run on the same column.

```
df.groupby('A').agg(['mean', 'std'])
```

[image]

```
df.groupby('A').agg(dict(B='sum', C=['mean', 'prod']))
```

[image]

Comment: fabulously tremendous answer!

Comment: By using `agg` how can I return to original data-frame `df`  exploding the aggregated columns?

Comment: @MAC To explode columns, use `transform`.