# Deduct 1st row value from subsequent rows for each group

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe like:

```
SEQ_N FREQ  VAL
ABC   1     121
ABC   1     130
ABC   1     127
ABC   1     116 
DEF   1     345
DEF   1     360
DEF   1     327
DEF   1     309
```

I want to subtract 1st row value from subsequent rows for each group.

Result:

```
SEQ_N FREQ  VAL  RES
ABC   1     121   0
ABC   1     130   9
ABC   1     127   6
ABC   1     116  -5
DEF   1     345   0
DEF   1     360   15
DEF   1     327  -18
DEF   1     309  -36
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Subtract column by [`Series.sub`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.sub.html) with [`transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) and [`first`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.first.html) for get first value per groups to `Series` with same size like original:

```
df['RES'] = df['VAL'].sub(df.groupby('SEQ_N')['VAL'].transform('first'))
print (df)
  SEQ_N  FREQ  VAL  RES
0   ABC     1  121    0
1   ABC     1  130    9
2   ABC     1  127    6
3   ABC     1  116   -5
4   DEF     1  345    0
5   DEF     1  360   15
6   DEF     1  327  -18
7   DEF     1  309  -36
```

Comment: What does transform do here? The link does not say much

Comment: @urdearboy it transforms the result which you are calling as a series for the groups, here it is the first value. you can test using `print(df.groupby('SEQ_N')['VAL'].transform('first'))` :)

Comment: @urdearboy -also maybe help [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40957932/2901002) answers.