# pandas, subtract dataframe from another, when column match

Tags: pandas

I have a dataframe (movielens dataset)

```
(Pdb) self.data_train.head()
       userId  movieId  rating   timestamp
65414     466      608     4.0   945139883
79720     547     6218     4.0  1089518106
63354     457     4007     3.5  1471383787
29923     213    59333     2.5  1462636955
63651     457   102194     2.5  1471383710
```

I found mean of each user's rating

```
 user_mean = self.data_train['rating'].groupby(self.data_train['userId']).mean()
(Pdb) user_mean.head()
userId
1    2.527778
2    3.426471
3    3.588889
4    4.363158
5    3.908602
```

I want to subtract this mean value from the first dataframe for the matching user.

Is there a way of doing it without a explicit for loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need [`GroupBy.transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) with `mean` for `Series`with same size like original `DataFrame`, so possible subtract column by [`Series.sub`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.sub.html):

```
s = self.data_train.groupby('userId')['rating'].transform('mean')
self.data_train['new'] = self.data_train['rating'].sub(s)
```

**Sample**: Changed data in `userId` for better sample

```
print (data_train)
       userId  movieId  rating   timestamp
65414     466      608     4.0   945139883
79720     466     6218     4.0  1089518106
63354     457     4007     3.5  1471383787
29923     466    59333     2.5  1462636955
63651     457   102194     2.5  1471383710

s = data_train.groupby('userId')['rating'].transform('mean')
print (s)
65414    3.5
79720    3.5
63354    3.0
29923    3.5
63651    3.0
Name: rating, dtype: float64

data_train['new'] = data_train['rating'].sub(s)
print (data_train)
       userId  movieId  rating   timestamp  new
65414     466      608     4.0   945139883  0.5
79720     466     6218     4.0  1089518106  0.5
63354     457     4007     3.5  1471383787  0.5
29923     466    59333     2.5  1462636955 -1.0
63651     457   102194     2.5  1471383710 -0.5
```

Comment: can you elaborate each step of `s = data_train.groupby('userId')['rating'].transform('mean')` line? I can't dicipher the documentation. or I can't see what they are by printing `data_train.groupby('userId')` `data_train.groupby('userId')['rating']` .... Thanks anyway

Comment: @eugene - So import part of code is [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/groupby.html#dataframe-column-selection-in-groupby) - `df['C'].groupby(df['A'])` (more verbose) is same like `df.groupby('A')['C']` (common use)

Comment: @eugene - difference between `transform` vs `aggregation` is possible check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40957932/2901002)

Comment: wow, much approachable document! thanks. wish pandas' doc is excutable as jupyter